# project.el: override project-find-regexp with use-package to show live results like project-find-file (preferably with consult)?

Tags: use-package, interactive, project, consult

When switching projects, there's a few commands available off the bat that can be selected from the mini-buffer after selecting a project.

`[f] Find file [g] Find regexp [d] Find directory ...`

Both find file and find directory and interactive. i.e., live results are shown as you type search terms.

However, Find regexp (`project-find-regexp` from `project.el`) does not. The prompt is simply: `Find regexp:`  and as you type there's no live results shown and therefore no immediate feedback as to whether the regex provided as matching any results.

How might I define `use-package` for project and/or `consult` to adjust this initial behaviour of `project-find-regexp`?

Some relevant snippets of my init.el are as follows:

```lisp
(use-package consult
  :bind (
          ("C-s" . consult-line)
          ("C-x b" . consult-buffer)
          ("M-g M-g" . consult-goto-line)
          ("M-g g" . consult-goto-line)
          ("M-s f" . consult-find)
          ("M-s r" . consult-ripgrep)
          ("M-y" . consult-yank-pop)
          )
  :commands (consult-completing-read-multiple)
  :config
  (setq consult-project-root-function
    (lambda ()
      (let ((p (project-current)))
        (when p (project-root p)))))

  (defvar rah/consult-line-map
    (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
      (define-key map "\C-s" #'vertico-next)
      map))

  (advice-add #'completing-read-multiple
    :override #'consult-completing-read-multiple)

  (consult-customize
    consult-line
    :history t ;; disable history
    :keymap rah/consult-line-map
    consult-buffer consult-find consult-ripgrep
    :preview-key (kbd "M-.")
    consult-theme
    :preview-key '(:debounce 1 any)
    )
  )

(use-package consult-dir
  :bind (
          ("C-x C-d" . consult-dir)
          )
  :bind (:map minibuffer-local-completion-map
          ("C-x C-d" . consult-dir)
          ("C-x C-j" . consult-dir-jump-file)
          ))

(use-package consult-project-extra
  :bind (
          ("C-c p f" . consult-project-extra-find)
          ("C-c p o" . consult-project-extra-find-other-window)
          ))

(use-package consult-xref
  :after (consult xref)
  :commands (consult-xref)
  :init
  (setq xref-show-definitions-function #'consult-xref
    xref-show-xrefs-function #'consult-xref)
  )

(use-package project
  :bind-keymap (
                 ("C-x p" . project-prefix-map)
                 )
  :bind (:map project-prefix-map
          ("m" . magit-project-status)
          )
  :commands (project-root)
  :config
  (add-to-list 'project-switch-commands '(magit-project-status "Magit") t)
  )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cat just use `consult-ripgrep` to override `project-find-regexp` through:

```lisp
(advice-add #'project-find-regexp :override #'consult-ripgrep)
```

Comment: Thanks @tianshu-wang that's perfect!